# CSS pseudo-class for having clicked on a <button>

Tags: css

It seems that `:active` only applies a `background` color at the instant when you have clicked on the `<button>` in the interim between click release. I basically would like to apply , if it exists, a pseudo-class that is invoked after the release of a click on a `<button>` element to demonstrate to the viewer that it has been toggled.

```
button:active{
   background:#FFFFFF;
}
```

UPDATE:

I changed the `<button>` to be an anchor tag. However, when I try

```
 #button-id:visited{ background:#FFFFFF;  }
```

It doesn't render the background color after I click the `<a>`

Here is the Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/y5apt5et/

Comment: make it an anchor tag and style it like a button. Then use :visited for what you need

Comment: If it's focusable, `:focus:not(:active)` would work. But that would also show up if someone tabbed to focus it, or, say, right clicked and dismissed the context menu.

Comment: `:visited` won't work because it is based on the `href` attribute of the link. In your case you should use e.g. jQuery to add and remove classes  on link click.

Comment: You can achieve this behavior with something called the checkbox hack (though it's not really a hack) by using `<input type="checkbox">` and the `:checked` pseudo-class in your CSS.

Answer (score 4):

[Here's a list of all CSS pseudo-classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes). There's nothing that works as a toggle button. Your best bet is to add an event listener that listens for a click on the button and adds or removes a class that represents being toggled.

Comment: That's not entirely true. `:checked` for checkboxes **is** a toggle, and when combined with a label, acts like a button to toggle desired styles behavior.