# Joomla fabrik form change button colour

Tags: css, joomla

Joomla - Fabrik form buttons.

I added a class in the form for the apply-button.

When I add the class in the user.css of the template the following works:

```
.btn-primary1 {background-color: green}
.btn-primary1:hover {background-color: blue)
```

This is not working:

```
.btn-primary1:active {background-color: blue}
.btn-primary1:visited {background-color: blue}
.btn-primary1:focus {background-color: blue}
```

The colour of the button must be blue when the user hit the apply-button.
But it goes back to green.
How can I solve this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: please try adding !important to those.

Comment: Hi, thanks, I added it but unfortunately it is not working.

Comment: can you share the URL?

Comment: @Maud This is very relevant reading https://stackoverflow.com/q/1677990/2943403

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/33621607/2943403

Comment: Are these button tags or a tags?